# Handling IllegalArgumentException in Pyspark ML

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, decision-tree

I'm having trouble while creating ML pipeline for DecisionTreeClassifier.

I'm working on linux attacks dataset with target variable 'attack''

I've the following code inplace:

```
inputCols = [col for col in df_memory.columns if col != "attack"
outputCols = [f"{col}_idx" for col in df_memory.columns if col not in ["attack"]]
outputCols.append('label')
stage_1 = StringIndexer(inputCols=inputCols, outputCols=outputCols)
inputCols_VA = [x for x in outputCols if x != "label"]
stage_2 = VectorAssembler(inputCols=inputCols_VA, outputCol="features")
print(inputCols_VA)
print(outputCols)
```

Printing the above gives me result as:

```html
['ts_idx', 'PID_idx', 'MINFLT_idx', 'MAJFLT_idx', 'VSTEXT_idx', 'VSIZE_idx', 'RSIZE_idx', 'VGROW_idx', 'RGROW_idx', 'MEM_idx', 'CMD_idx', 'type_idx']
['ts_idx', 'PID_idx', 'MINFLT_idx', 'MAJFLT_idx', 'VSTEXT_idx', 'VSIZE_idx', 'RSIZE_idx', 'VGROW_idx', 'RGROW_idx', 'MEM_idx', 'CMD_idx', 'type_idx', 'label']
```

```
stage_3 = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='label', featuresCol = 'features')
```

Creating stages to pipeline:

```
pipeline =  Pipeline(stages=[stage_1,stage_2,stage_3])
model = pipeline.fit(train_memory_df)
```

Above code gives me following error:

```html
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of input columns does not match output columns
```

How to fix this?

my training dataframe has following columns:

```html
['ts',
 'PID',
 'MINFLT',
 'MAJFLT',
 'VSTEXT',
 'VSIZE',
 'RSIZE',
 'VGROW',
 'RGROW',
 'MEM',
 'CMD',
 'attack',
 'type']
```

Comment: if you want to use `attack` as the label, you need to add `inputCols.append('attack')` before setting stage_1, so that `attack` is the last entry of the list and # of entries from inputCols and outputCols match.